# Correlation in R with imbalanced data

Tags: r

Let's say I have two vectors of different length. Of course, this will fail when I run cor.test in R.

```
x = rnorm(1,3,5,7,2,12,13,14,5,16) 
y = rnorm(1,4,5,6,7)

cor.test(x,y)

> cor.test(x,y)
Error in cor.test.default(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Obviously, regression also fails in this scenario given the length imbalance.

```
> lm(y~x)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')
```

What is the proper statistical solution to get some sort of "correlation" or "association" metric when two variables are imbalanced? Any explanation of the stats behind it would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: These variables have no explicit connection, so what do you mean by "correlation" or "association"?  How could that possibly apply?

Comment: Let's say that they were connected...updated the data so that they should have a strong positive covariance

Comment: It is meaningless to assert "they were connected": you merely have two batches of numbers.  There is no way, without additional information, to infer anything whatsoever about any relationship between them.

Comment: I have voted to reopen on the grounds that this question is answerable, though I think it could benefit from a change of title ("data sets of different sizes" perhaps, rather than "imbalanced"?). I think the appropriate answer is to explain what [bivariate data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivariate_data) really means, and why "correlation" or "association" only make sense in that context. Without pairing, the concept is meaningless.

Comment: @Silverfish, are you planning to provide such an answer, if it is reopened?

Comment: @gung Quite possibly, time-depending. I think it might be worth further searching for a duplicate first, since I have the feeling such a question must have been asked before (though cannot recall seeing it myself!)

Comment: @Silverfish, when you have an answer worked up for this, ping me. I lean towards leaving this closed, but if you have an answer, I'll open it for you.

Comment: `x = rnorm(1,3,5,7,2,12,13,14,5,16) ` is not even a valid `R` expression and just throws an error.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia writes "Correlation is any of a broad class of statistical relationships involving dependence" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence ) 
You can only have it in dependend data. Usually, when you write `R`-code like this:

```
x <- c(3, 4, 5, 6)
y <- c(1, 6, 7, 8)
cor(x, y, method="...")
```

this implies, that the first element in `x` has something in common with the first element in `y` and the second has something in common with the second and the third with the third and so on. 
Correlation searches for things like "If some element in `x` is large, does the **corresponding** element in `y` have a tendency to be large as well?". Now, in something like

```
x = c(1,3,5,7,2,12,13,14,5,16) 
y = c(1,4,5,6,7)
```

There is no information, what `y` values should be large or small if `x` is 12, 13, 14, 5 or 16. Therefore, `R` throws an error so you can think about what went wrong.

**Either** your data has no clear definition of what a correlation amongst them should be, because it is not dependend data, **or** there are data points missing, which needs to be cleared by inserting `NA` where the data is missing

This would work:

```
x = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 12, 13, 14, 5, 16) 
y = c(1, 4, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA)
cor(x, y, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Because now it is clear, which element in `x`belongs to which in `y`.

For a more visual and maybe intuitive approach, let's for the moment consider Pearson correlation as an answer to the question, how well a regression line fits the data points in a scatter plot (with a grain of salt). Take your data example of 10 `x` values and 5 `y` values and see, if you can draw that in a scatter plot.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer I was going to put except that I would have really emphasised one more point: *simply the fact that two univariate datasets have the same length, does **not** mean that the "correlation" between them is meaningful*. Unless we have been given more information, we do not know that the first entry of the first dataset has any meaningful correspondence with the first entry of the second.

Comment: When the datasets are of different lengths, it is obvious there *cannot* be such a correspondence; but if you have e.g. height data for 10 people and weight data for 10 different people, then we still cannot work out whether higher values of "weight" corresponded to higher or lower values of "height".